# Report viewer for wsus

Tags: sharepoint, wsus

Is there any way to integrate microsoft report viewer with sharepoint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i locked it up and found this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100701172809/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sharepoint/archive/2007/02/19/microsoft-sql-server-2005-sp2-reporting-services-integration-with-wss-3-0-and-moss-2007.aspx) which i think a great reference about the report integration.